# Can't access my app using local ip address when connected using Docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, codeigniter-3

I have my Codeigniter/PHP app set up in docker-compose. When I run `localhost:8893` or `127.0.0.1:8893` it works perfectly. Now I want to share that address with my friends but when I access the same thing with my IP address `192.168.100.96:8893` it just keeps loading, with no response.

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  test-webserver:
    image: thecodingmachine/php:8.0-v4-apache-node16
    container_name: test-webserver
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    environment:
#      PHP_EXTENSIONS: apcu pdo_mysql opcache redis zip gd yaml exif xdebug
      PHP_EXTENSIONS: opcache redis zip gd yaml exif xdebug
      PHP_EXTENSION_GD: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_MYSQLI: 1
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html/
      APACHE_RUN_GROUP: www-data # use www-data user in container.. which is also used on most webservers for deployer
      APACHE_RUN_USER: www-data
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: 1
    depends_on:
      - test-mariadb
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    expose:
      - "8893"
    ports:
      - "8893:80"
    networks:
      - test.network
  test-mariadb:
    container_name: test-mariadb
    image: mariadb:10.3.36
    networks:
      - test.network
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=test123
    volumes:
      - ../mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - "40000"
    ports:
      - "40000:3306"
  test-phpmyadmin:
    container_name: test-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    networks:
      - test.network
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=test-mariadb
      - PMA_PORT=3306
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=test123
      - UPLOAD_LIMIT=2048M
    expose:
      - "40001"
    ports:
      - "40001:80"
networks:
  test.network:
    driver: bridge
    name: test.network
    external: true
```

[image]

When I try to access the same with my IP address, it keeps loading.

[image]

You can confirm my local IP as well.

[image]

Here is my env config.

```
APP_DB_HOSTNAME=test-mariadb
APP_DB_USERNAME=root
APP_DB_PASSWORD=test123
APP_DB_NAME=my_test_db
APP_DB_PORT=3306
APP_DB_PREFIX=tbl
```

Can anyone figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: `192.168.x.x` is private IP address range, your friend can not access this ip from outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked again and it's working, in incognito mode, other browsers and my friend PC as well. Don't know what I did wrong in my current chrome browser. Question is completed now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `network` block?

In my development environment I don't configure it and it's working fine.

If you only need to expose your app.... you don't need expose your DB.

Comment: I don't think so. If I remove the `network` block from the `test-service` container, it shows me an error. `mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known` from `localhost:8893`. Also, the error still persists of not being able to access using IP Address `192.168.100.96:8893`